# API how to add followers on foursquare

Tags: android, api, foursquare

I'm writing a web service that is going to communicate with the foursquare API, it should call their API, do some processing, and pass that new info to an android app.
On the API documentation page of Foursquare I couldn't find endpoints for getting followers, and following of a user.

Somehow, I guessed they were there, and there they are...

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/followers
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/following
```

They are both GET types.

Missing piece of a puzzle is how can I add user that I want to follow through their API.

Comment: I got answer from official api support team.


"You can follow a Foursquare brand page (such as the New York Times) in this way: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/pages/follow. Following users is a little more protected due to historical reasons but we should be officially opening this capability up to everyone soon."